# Converting struct in main() into function version

Tags: c, csv

I'm new to C programming. I just figured out how to read csv files into C by struct, but struggling to convert the script into a function, then call this function in int main(). I'll need to read loads of csv files so a function will be very helpful.

Here is my code which runs successfully (non-function version):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAXROWS 2

struct cudaScenarioStruct{
    char *type;
    int trial;
    int yPC;
    int yPE;
    int n;
};

struct cudaScenarioStruct cudaScenario[MAXROWS];


int main(){
int rowIndex = 0;
char line[128];
char* token = NULL;
FILE* fp = fopen("C:/Users/ms710557/Desktop/cudaScenario1(2).csv","r");
if (fp != NULL){
    while (fgets( line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL && rowIndex < MAXROWS){

        cudaScenario[rowIndex].type = malloc(2);
        token = strtok(line, ",");
        strcpy(cudaScenario[rowIndex].type, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        cudaScenario[rowIndex].trial = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        cudaScenario[rowIndex].yPC = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        cudaScenario[rowIndex].yPE = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        cudaScenario[rowIndex].n = atoi(token);

        rowIndex++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

for (int i = 0; i < MAXROWS; ++i){
    printf("%s, %i, %i, %i, %i \n", cudaScenario[i].type, cudaScenario[i].trial, cudaScenario[i].yPC, cudaScenario[i].yPE, cudaScenario[i].n);
}

return 0;
}
```

The results look like this:

```
NI, 1, 61, 55, 80 
NI, 2, 54, 59, 80
```

However when I convert it into a function and include the function in int main(), it's just not working... I've been googling for hours and couldn't find out why. This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXROWS 2

struct cudaScenarioStruct{
    char *type;
    int trial;
    int yPC;
    int yPE;
    int n;
};


struct cudaScenarioStruct *readCudaScenarioData(){
    struct cudaScenarioStruct csvData[MAXROWS];

    int rowIndex = 0;
    char line[128];
    char* token = NULL;
    FILE* fp = fopen("C:/Users/ms710557/Desktop/cudaScenario1(2).csv","r");
    if (fp != NULL){
        while (fgets( line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL && rowIndex < MAXROWS){

            csvData[rowIndex].type = malloc(2);
            token = strtok(line, ",");
            strcpy(csvData[rowIndex].type, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            csvData[rowIndex].trial = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            csvData[rowIndex].yPC = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            csvData[rowIndex].yPE = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            csvData[rowIndex].n = atoi(token);
            rowIndex++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return csvData;
}




int main()
{

    struct cudaScenarioStruct *cudaScenario;
    cudaScenario = readCudaScenarioData();

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXROWS; ++i){
        printf("%s, %i, %i, %i, %i \n", cudaScenario[i].type, 
cudaScenario[i].trial, cudaScenario[i].yPC, cudaScenario[i].yPE, 
cudaScenario[i].n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala hmm how should I correct it.. Make the variable not local?

Comment: You can use an array from the caller, or you can allocate it using `malloc`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ahh just saw you directed me to another answer. thanks a lot!